# Windows Forms progress bar while system performs background task asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

Using Windows Forms, I want to write an `onclick` event that reads a sim card. This function renders the application unresponsive for 5000 milliseconds.

I want to run both functions at the same time, independent from each other

```
private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    // run both functions at the same time  
    barraProgresso(5000);         // progress bar          
    run_background_function();    // renders app unresponsive
}

private void barraProgresso(int tempo)
{
    for (int progresso = 0; progresso <= 100; progresso++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progresso;
        Thread.Sleep(tempo / 100);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Correct.  Get rid of the `Thread.Sleep`. It's blocking.  We don't know what you are doing in that other function.

Comment: As @LarsTech said, you are blocked your working thread with `barraProgresso`.
Have you tried to make `barraProgresso` async and call by `Task.Run`?

Comment: @LarsTech The other function is a tool from a SDK for reading smart cards, I don't have any controll over that

Comment: @imansafari can you code an example with theese function names?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which simulates work being done along with a cancellation option.

[image]

Mock up for work being done in a separate class from the form.

```
public class Operations
{
    public static async Task AsyncMethod(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        for (int index = 0; index <= 100; index++)
        {
            // Simulate an async call that takes some time
            // to complete like uploading a file
            await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            progress?.Report(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Form code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = 
        new CancellationTokenSource();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;

        var cancelled = false;

        if (_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }


        var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);

        try
        {
            await Operations.AsyncMethod(progressIndicator, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            cancelled = true;
        }

        if (cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
        }
    }

    private void CancelOperationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void ReportProgress(int value)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        LblPercent.Text = $"{value} %";
    }
}
```